# Expressão Linq dando errado quando evita repetições em um List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou tentando evitar dados duplicados antes de dar um ***set value***. Tenho uma classe `Player` que tem em si uma propriedade chamada `NickName`, essa classe está inserida no `List`.

Classe Player:

```
public class Player
{
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}
```

Na parte do `set`, preciso inserir tudo dentro da variável `player`, onde não tenha `player.NickName`.

Metodo get e set:

```
public List<Player> player = new List<Player>();

public List<Player> Player
{
   get { return player; }
   set { player = value.Where(x => !player.Contains(x.NickName)); }
}
```

O modelo acima dá erro dizendo que não é possível converter `string` para `Player`. Como posso fazer da maneira correta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código está confuso e parece ter erros conceituais, mas acredito que quer isto:

```
set { player = value.Where(x => !player.Any(y => x.NickName.Contains(y.NickName))).ToList(); }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/ContainsString.cs).

Você tem que analisar item por item da lista para depois ver se o nome bate, por isso tem que usar um [`Any()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2). Não posso garantir que dá o resultado desejado porque a pergunta não é tão clara quanto aos critérios, mas pelo menos resolve o erro que existia. Quando o LINQ parece difícil faça manualmente que é mais rápido e simples. O LINQ só deveria ser usado para facilitar, quando ele complica ele não vale a pena.